# Pulling goodness of fit data from Minitab

Tags: excel, vba, automation, minitab

using the command prompt "DCapa C1 1; All; BoxCox; Johnson 0.10; RDescriptive; RFitTests; REstimate" I can run an individual distribution analysis of a column of data. Are there commands that would pull the "goodness of fit" data, so that I can identify the best fit distribution for a capability analysis? I am hoping to fully automate the process of "run individual analysis--> pull correct best fit distribution based on goodness of fit data --> run correct capability analysis."

I am trying to automate this via excel VBA and the minitab command line, but if there is an easier way to do this I would be all ears.

Thanks!

I have created this VBA script to run an individual dist analysis, but now would like to pull the goodness of fit data:

Sub IndividualDistributionAnalysis()

```
' Create a new Minitab Application object
Dim mtbApp As Object
Dim myProj As Object
Dim myWksh As Object
Dim cmdProc As Object

Set mtbApp = CreateObject("Mtb.Application")

' Set Minitab to be visible
mtbApp.UserInterface.Visible = True
  
mtbApp.Open "C:\Users\SV001496\Documents\vba test\Test"

Set myProj = mtbApp.ActiveProject
Set myWksh = myProj.ActiveWorksheet
myProj.ExecuteCommand ("DCapa C1 1; All; BoxCox; Johnson 0.10; RDescriptive; RFitTests; REstimate")

   
mtbApp.Save “C:\Users\SV001496\Documents\vba test\Test result"
```

End Sub

I was hoping the GetData column object would be able to pull the AD/P data from the goodness of fit data, but that pulls from the columns in the worksheet and not the columns in the results from the individual dist. analysis.